# Pass mutableList through intent

Tags: java, android-intent, arraylist, kotlin, mutablelist

I have a `mutableList`.

```
var newList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
```

How to pass `newList` through intent?

I tried this but not working.

```
 mIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("mFilePath", ArrayList(newList))
```

**Error**

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch:  required:
>   java.util.ArrayList! found:
>   kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* =
>   java.util.ArrayList */

Comment: Why not `putStringArrayList`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was able to fix it.

```
  mIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("mFilePath", ArrayList(newList))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("NEW_LIST", ArrayList(newList))
```

Comment: `Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required:
java.util.ArrayList<out Parcelable!>!
found:
kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String!> /* = java.util.ArrayList<String!> */`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it on arraylist and pass as putParcelableArrayListExtra through intent

you can create separate model class and add that model class to your arraylist and make it Parcelize through this you can achieve this@Parcelize 
class model:Parcelable{
}